# Why does this code work in Objective-C? I'm getting BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, c

```
int RandomSource_next(int bits, double* seed) {
    *seed = (((long long) *seed * 0x5DEECE66DLL) + 0xBLL) & ((1LL << 48) - 1);
    return (int)((signed long long) *seed >> (48 - bits));
}
```

I think it got something to do with the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are passing incorrect address as `seed`. Maybe you're passing not an address but a value?

The following should work

```
double seed = 0;

RandomSource_next(48, &seed);
```

The following should crash

```
RandomSource_next(48, 0);
```